# Expression requestAttributes.email is undefined on line 468, column 66

Tags: freemarker

working fine but i am getting error in log error.log fine can u plesae help.

[ Log4JLoggerFactory.java:96 :ERROR] Template processing error: "Expression requestAttributes.email is undefined on line 468, column 66 in component://osafe/webapp/osafe/common/eCommerceOrderPaymentMethods.ftl."

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${requestAttributes.email}"/>

Answer (score 0):

This means that `email` in `requestAttributes` was `null` or non-existent. If that's expected, use `${requestAttributes.email!}`.

Comment: "${requestAttributes.email!}"/> is same as "${requestAttributes.email?if_exists}"/> please assist

Comment: `?if_exists` was deprecated long ago. But otherwise they are almost the same. The difference is that `?if_exists` can also be used as boolean or as directive (like `<#if foo?if_exists>` or `<@foo?if_exists />`), while `foo!` can only be used as string, sequence or hash. See: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_depr_builtin.html

Comment: Actually, your comment was specifically about `${foo!}` vs `${foo?if_exists}`, in which case the answer is that they are the same.